# Dejar copiar números de 17 dígitos y agregar un punto después del 15 dígito, en caso tal no lo deje pegar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy haciendo una función donde el usuario escriba números de 17 dígitos y que después del 15 número le ponga un punto algo así: (123698521036978.41), *(Hasta ahí todo bien)*, Pero si el usuario copia un número y lo pega en el input lo deja pegar normal, lo que necesito es si el usuario pega un número en el input y es menor de 17 números ejemplo (5698721), NO lo deje pegar, y si escribe alfanúmericos ejemplo (543jhfsdj599) NO lo deje pegar, pero en caso tal que el copie y pegue los 17 números lo deje pegar, y le agregue automáticamente un punto después del número 15, ejemplo si copia 56231058945600231 al pegar al input quede 562310589456002.31

Código Jquery

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('#txtJobID').keypress(function(tecla) {
            if(tecla.charCode < 48 || tecla.charCode > 57){
                return false;
            }else{
                if(jQuery(this).val().toString().length <= 17){
                    if(jQuery(this).val().toString().length == 15)
                        jQuery(this).val(jQuery(this).val() + ".");
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lo primero que te sugiero que pongas en tu input element el **type='number**'algo asi

```
 <input type="number" id="txtJobID" />
```

esto evitara que puedan pegrar ni utilizar caracteres invalidos

en lugar de controlar la validacion en el keypress te sujiero colocarla en el on change esto hara que se valide cuando se salga del campo o se le de enter

```
    function validaNumero(e) {
        var val = jQuery(e.target).val().toString();
        console.log(val, val.indexOf("e"));
        if (val.indexOf("e") < 0) {
            val = `${val.substr(0, val.length - 2)}.${val.substr(val.length - 2, 2)}`;
            console.log(val);
            if (Number(val) > 0 && val.length == 18) {
                jQuery(e.target).val(val);
            } else {
                jQuery(e.target).val("");
            }
        } else {
            jQuery(e.target).val("");
        }
    }
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#txtJobID').change(validaNumero);
        jQuery('#txtJobID').keydown(validaNumero);
    });
```

Esta solucion es mas adecuada que la que te di originalmente, elimine la funcion anonima para poder usar la misma funcion con varios eventos

Comment: Si sirvi, si pongo ejemplo jgfds54kxns<z al cambiar el campo queda vacío (Y así esta bien), pero si yo copio y pego este texto ee.ee.eeee.e...0,.e-2...e-2,2e.e0.e18ee.e.eeee.e. uno cambia de campo y el texto sigue visible (Y ya cambie el input por NUMBER). y nose porque pasará eso.

Comment: Es por que el caracter ee. se usa para denotar error y para la notacion cientifica de numeros muy grandes

Comment: por cierto que navegador estas usando?

Comment: ¿Como solucionaría ese error?, y el navegador es Google Chrome.

Comment: Modifique la respuesta para que te fuera mas util, al poner la funcion tambien en el key down me aseguro que su teclean la e sea eliminado el valor invalido